# Windows 7 SP1 doesn't recognize SHA-256 *.exe timestamp file sign

Tags: windows-7, windows

**Windows 7 SP1** doesn't recognize **SHA-256** `*.exe` timestamp file sign, MS has released a patch ([KB3033929](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityAdvisories/2015/3033929)), i have tried to install but a warning says me that is already installed.

I have also checked with the command:

```
dism /online /get-packages | findstr KB3033929
```

and the packages is found.

Why sha-256 doesn't works? the same file is good on Windows 8 and Windows 10.

Comment: Find KB3033929 in windows updates and uninstall it, then reinstall the package.

Comment: thanks, uninstall/reinstall has fixed the issue...

Comment: I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find KB3033929 in windows updates and uninstall it, then reinstall the package.